# flask versus traditional LAMP server

Tags: flask

What are the advantages of using Flask versus installing a traditional server such as a LAMP server that includes Python?  My school's web development club uses Flask because it is easier to teach to students and does not require setting up a server.  However, is Flask better than using a traditional server for long term projects?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

LAMP is apache, mysql and php. Flask is just a python web framework, no database, no server, no batteries included so in my opinion Flask vs LAMP is just comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: To expand on this, Flask would be closer as a replacement for the "PHP" part of "LAMP" than a replacement for all the parts of "LAMP". Writing in Flask with the development server doesn't require setting up a web server (like Apache), but that is simply designed to ease development. Eventually, if you are using Flask in production (as part of a "real" web site) you WOULD set up a server, which might include setting up the other parts of a LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, and MySQL).

Comment: According to Wikipedia and LAMP server is defined as: 
L- Linux,
A- Apache
M- MySQL, MariaDB, or MongoDB
P- PHP, Perl, or Python

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to develop web application using Flask is much easier than learning all the LAMP approach. 
I've learn to use it in the RESTful way that most web applications work.
You can use modwsgi to apply it in a Apache Server or you can use other deployment methods.
In my opinion all those frameworks like RoR, Django, Flask, that are running away from using PHP have a good future, but I haven't implemented a big application to test it myself.

Besides, Flask has a good documentation